# Can R assign values to variables inside loop parenthesis?

Tags: r

where x is set to i inside the parenthesis

```
i <- 2
for(x  <-  i in x:10)
{
  print(x)
}
```

this should print 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

can this be done?

essentially what i am trying to do is convert this Javascript code into R

```
var J =  ;
var Found = false;
var Counter = 0;
var X = 0;
var Truth = false;
var Strength = 2;
    for (J = Strength;(J < 80)&&(Found == false); J++)
    {
        Price = low(-J); //p=25
        X = J + 1;  //x=3
        Truth = true;
        for (X = (J + 1); ((X - J) <= Strength)&&(Truth); X++)
        {
            if (Price > low(-X)) Truth = false;
        }
        X = J - 1;
        for (X = (J - 1);((J - X) <= Strength)&&(Truth); X--)
        {
            if (Price >= low(-X)) Truth = false;
        }
        if (Truth) Counter++;
        if (Counter >= 1) Found = true;
    }

    if (Found) SwingLow = Price;

    else SwingLow = -1;
```

The code iterates through a time series and finds fractal patterns in financial data.

http://www.timingthemarket.com/uploads/3/0/9/1/3091598/9585500_orig.png?876

If someone can convert just the for(***) part i should be able to do the rest. 
I didn't write the original code, and to me it seems kinda strange the way its done.

Comment: What is the desired output of the above loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but i think what are you asking is not possible in R. If you use `?"for"` you can see the precise guide for the `for` control loops.

Here it is stated that the `cond` inside the parenthesis must be a logical vector. This in my opinion rule out the possibilities of assign variable inside the `cond` even because if you type in your console you can see that:

```
> is.logical(x <- 1)
[1] FALSE
```

#### Edit

As other users have noted you can use this code:

```
for(i in ((x<-i):10))
    {
      print(x)
    }
```

and it works but in fact I think it not reproduces what you wanted but only a (pointless in my opinion) symbol change because I guess R interprets it as you are saying:

> for `i` do something but `i` is now called `x` so do the previous action on `x`.

After all your intent might be achieved with a simpler code like:

```
> i <- 4
> for(i in i:10) print(i)
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
```

Maybe it is useful for and allows you to do not asking a variable inside the `cond` of the `for` loops.

Comment: basically the answer was

Comment: for(i in ((x<-i):10))

Comment: j <- 2
x <- j+1
x
for(x in ((x-j):10))
{
  print(x)

}

Comment: x prints out from 1-10, rather than 3-10